# How to keep a log of user activity and show in an Android App?

Tags: android, logging, activitylog

I am working on an android App where I need to keep user activity log of the logged in user.

Suppose if I like one page of the app, it will show in the user activity log section.

Please help me how to do that?

Comment: do you mean android logcat ?

Comment: So, you need persistent data [hopefully] per user. Based on your requirement I suggest you need to come up with a database schema with [possibly] multiple tables and use SQLite. This will keep the user data locally and is just one way your problem can be solved.

Comment: @Shaishav : thanks for your suggestion. if you can provide me any other alternative, that would be great for me.

Comment: @meysam : No, I did not mean android logcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple users logging into the app then you need to design a database based on your requirements and put that database in a remote location so your users can access it from anywhere. You can either buy your own space at a hosting site (you will need to interface your database to app manually) or use a web database service like Firebase, Cloudboost, etc. (their SDK will allow you to interface app and database, hence integration should be easier).

You need look at your needs and budget as some of the above services may not be free and I suggest you do a thorough research before selecting one.